# Java servlet synchronize doGet inside doPost

Tags: java, email, servlets

I'm working on register's email confirmation.

Firstly, i creating random value from `doPost()` and sending this to final email as activation link:

```
int token = new Random().nextInt(999999-100000) + 100000;
sendMail mailAgent = new sendMail("Hello!", "Hello, Link: "+ request.getRequestURL().toString()+"?Sender="+nick+"&Token="+token);
mailAgent.to = "target@mail.com";
mailAgent.send();
```

...the message sent fine, but i have to get this value back as well.

The only idea how to - begin listen GET requests after `mailAgent.send()` method. It implies to freeze script's execution there.

I would to do something like this:

```
mailAgent.send();
doGet(request,response); 
// Will fire right after call, but i want to listen requests from here
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your question is not clear. You want to coordinate(don't say synchronize, it implies something else) the execution of `doGet` and `doPost` in the same servlet?

Comment: Sorry. I want to make a `doGet` listener inside `doPost`. Freeze `doPost` until i receive new GET query. To be clear, i'll be glad to any other solutions.

Comment: @Vossen if you do that, all your users will be mad. Believe me :)

Comment: @Vossen tip: you may want to read a bit on how the container (eg Tomcat) and the servlet work together - accepting the request is not something the servlet does, it just gets called by the container when a request is received.

Comment: @fvu, ty, i'll consider it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to register the user once he has clicked on the link, containing a random token, sent in an email. The user might click on this link a long, long time after you have sent the mail. Your server might have rebooted, a lot of things might have happened.

So, store the random token in your database, along with the user ID, before sending it to the user by mail.

When the user reads the mail, clicks on the link and thus sends back the token, check that the token he has sent is the same as the one stored in database. If it is, then mark the user as registered.